# Using Jquery, how to Grab all links with class 'c1' and has abcdef in the href

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Using jquery, I want to get all links on the page with the css class 'c1' and that have 'abcdef' in the url of the href.

So far I know how to do:

```
$(".c1")
```

Comment: better get all the links first an then perform a regex on them.

Answer (score 7):

You can use an [attribute-contains selector (`[attr*=val]`)](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/), like this:

```
$("a.c1[href*=abcdef]")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
$('a.c1[href*="abcdef"]')
```

For more on jQuery selectors see [Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)